# How does lower level module and higher level module communicate in golang

Tags: oop, go

In the following code, I have a lower level module `RelationshipBrowser` defined a `FindAllChildrenOf` method and I have a struct `Relationships` that has the property `relations` which is a slice and another struct named `Research` which as the property `browser`. I declared a receiver function `FindAllChildrenOf` for `Relationships` and another receiver function `Investigate` for `Research`, I think my question is, when I implement the logics in the function `Investigate` it's clearly calling the browser interface to trigger the function `FindAllChildrenOf` and go automatically knows that I am referring to type `Relationship`. My confusion is, how does RelationshipBrowser and Relationships connect in this context while they seem to have no connection?

```
const (
    Parent Relationship = iota
    Child
    Sibiling
)

type Person struct {
    name string
}

type Info struct{
    from *Person
    relatiionship Relationship
    to *Person
}

// low-level module
type RelationshipBrowser interface{
    FindAllChildrenOf(name string)[]*Person
    
}

type Relationships struct{
    relations []Info
}

func (r *Relationships)AddParentAndChild(parent,child *Person){
        r.relations = append(r.relations, Info{parent,Parent,child})
        r.relations = append(r.relations, Info{child,Child,parent})
    }

func (r *Relationships)FindAllChildrenOf(name string)[]*Person{
    result:= make([]*Person,0)
    for i,v:= range r.relations{
        if v.relatiionship == Parent && v.from.name==name{
            result = append(result, r.relations[i].to)
        }     
    }
    return result
}
// high-level module



type Research struct{
// break DIP
    // relationships Relationships 
    browser RelationshipBrowser
}

func (r *Research)Investigate(){
    // relations:= r.relationships.relations
    // for _, rel := range relations{
    //  if rel.from.name == "John" && rel.relatiionship == Parent{
    //      fmt.Println("John has a child called", rel.to.name)
    //  }
    // }
        children:=r.browser.FindAllChildrenOf("John")
        for _,child:=range children{
            fmt.Println("John has a child called", child.name)
        }

}

func main(){
    parent:= Person{"John"}
    child1:= Person{"Chris"}
    child2:= Person{"Matt"}
    relationships:= Relationships{}
    relationships.AddParentAndChild(&parent,&child1)
    relationships.AddParentAndChild(&parent,&child2)
    r := Research{&relationships}
    r.Investigate()

}
```

Comment: Interfaces in golang are implicit. https://tour.golang.org/methods/10

Answer (score 0):

> go automatically knows that I am referring to type Relationship.

Yes, because Go knows the exact address of the **RelationshipBrowser**, so it can know everything if it want.
You can know everything too, through the reflection, see https://go.dev/blog/laws-of-reflection

In your code, you explicitly pass the address here:

```
r := Research{&relationships}
```

RelationshipBrowser and Relationships connect together by this address, because Research think of it as a RelationshipBrowser, but it's actually a Relationships.

Answer (score -2):

I just figured out that by calling `r.Investigate`, the program knows I am referring to the `Relationship` struct. I am still a go beginner, so the learning curve is deep.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).